# P1-P10 fields in .NET Runtime error (Application event log)

Tags: sharepoint, iis-6, .net-3.5

Our Application event log is showing several .NET runtime errors (Event ID 5000) that look like this:

EventType ulsexception12, P1 w3wp.exe, P2 6.0.3790.3959, P3 45d691cc, P4 missing, P5 missing, P6 missing, P7 missing, P8 missing, P9 c0000005, P10 837l.

The sources of these errors is SharePoint, but I cannot find any backing detail about the "P" fields. Does anyone know what each of the P1-P10 values represent?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what those mean, but in my experience you see that type of event log message when you have a thread with an unhandled exception.

I'd suggest:

1. Ensure all of your threads have top level exception handlers, and log exceptions
2. Install an application exception handler, which won't stop your app from crashing, but will enable you to log the exception with some useful details, not the useless message you get above :)

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx

Answer (score 1):

These are internal SharePoint errors. Sometimes they are caused by bugs in custom code if a stack overflow or something else unexpected happens. Usually however they are caused by bugs in SharePoint... :-(

You may be able to get some clues by checking the ULS logs in the "12 Hive" at the time the crash occurs. Match the time of the logged event with the time in the ULS log.

If it looks like SharePoint is at fault, look at updating your farm to the latest service pack and CU which may resolve it (obviously test this first). You may also like to turn on error reporting in SharePoint Central Administration and Windows so Microsoft are sent the crash dumps and hopefully eventually fix whatever caused it.